# Is there any way to convert the matlab code into codesys?

Tags: matlab, codesys, iec61131-3

I have a matlab code which i want to convert into the codesys structured text language. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Simulink PLC Coder](https://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-plc-coder.html) to

> Generate IEC 61131-3 Structured Text and Ladder Diagrams for PLCs and PACs

Comment: had a look at it, i guess it wont solve my problem as i have a complex matlab code. Need to rethink how it can be done